# Has this type of calculus generalization been studied?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

[The product calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral) is mentioned in [this generalized calculus page](http://math2.org/math/paper/contents.htm).  It is essentially the continuous analogue of the [discrete product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_product).  The continuous product essentially takes a product and uses infinitesimals to calculate a continuous version of a prodct.  In other words, the product calculus essentially calculates:

$$\text{Product Integral}(f(x)) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=an}^{bn}{\frac{f(k/n)}{n}}$$

Are there studies on this type of more generalized calculus, where other forms of continuous integrals are examined?  In other words, are there studies that include basic calculus as well as the product calculus and other types of calculus such as division calculus or exponential calculus?

Comment: Have you looked at the references from the Wikipedia article? There seems to be at least one book, freely available online, on the subject.

Comment: @Chappers:  I should have looked more closely.  There are books on product integration, which I am looking into.  I'm still very much interested in a generalization that goes beyond product calculus.

Comment: John von Neumann published work  on continuously iterated integrals, in which instead of iterating integration  with respect to finitely many variables, there is instead a continuum of iterations.

Comment: @user254665:  That sounds a bit like the fractional calculus.  I'm really more interested in alternative calculi based on a function, such as a product (the Product calculus), a sum (Riemann Calculus), a quotient, an exponent, etc.  I'm not quite sure yet how I could employ von Neumann's calculus in this respect.

Comment: There are numerous integrals in measure theory... Is that not the direction you mean?

Comment: @rschwieb:  I'm really looking for the following, which will perhaps make things more clear.  High-school calculus can be found by a limit $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}}$.  For product calculus the limit is $\lim_{h\to \infty}\prod_{k=ah}^{bh}{\frac{f(k/h)}{h}}$, which equals $\lim_{h\to \infty}e^{\sum_{k=ah}^{bh}{\ln{\frac{f(k/h)}{h}}}}.$  There's a way to find an equivalent summation in each type of calculus.  So I'm looking into if anyone has studied other functions, such as $\lim_{h\to \infty}\sin\left({\sum_{k=ah}^{bh}{\sin^{-1}{\frac{f(k/h)}{h}}}}\right).$

Comment: @rschwieb: To be clear, these are functions for the derivative.  And I don't know measure theory, so measure theory could be what I'm looking for.  But here's the analogy:  we can go from discrete sums to continuous sums.  We can go from discrete products to continuous products, as in the product calculus.  Can we go from something like discrete sines, quotients, or exponents to continuous sines, quotients, or exponents?

Comment: @rschwieb: One more comment - sorry to write so much - it looks like measure theory could possibly be what I'm after.  It looks like one could apply a function to an interval, and come up with something like the sums I mentioned.  Does this seem to match your understanding of it?

Comment: See also [list of derivatives and integrals in alternative calculi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_derivatives_and_integrals_in_alternative_calculi).

Answer (score 2):

The 1970s book [Non-Newtonian Calculus](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=RLuJmE5y8pYC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=non%20newtonian%20calculus&ots=mkA6yngspU&sig=-53qKW0I7s11DC3797JJIPE6TfY#v=onepage&q=non%20newtonian%20calculus&f=false) studies a few, including the harmonic calculus based on the reciprocal function, the quadratic calculus based on the squaring function, and multiplicative calculus (or geometric, as they call it - multiplicative is the more modern name) based on the exponential. It also has a chapter on the general case for any pair of bijections among the real numbers.

The only one which I know has really been studied since this book came out is the multiplicative one. It is known that others exist but they seem to have remained unused.